# Unicode over Ajax not rendering correctly

Tags: javascript, ajax, unicode

I have searched for anything related to this, but not found anything directly equivalent, and nothing that has helped. I have a very simple application that fetches data from the server using Ajax (vanilla Javascript) but the Unicode characters are not being transferred correctly. My reasoning is that this is a client side problem, because if I access the Ajax URL directly from a browser address bar, it displays correctly.

I have put a console.log into the Javascript as the first thing it does on receipt of a response, and it is already corrupted at this point. I have added xmlhttp.overrideMimeType('text/plain;charset=utf-8'); but that had no visible effect.

I have created a minimal web page that exhibits the behaviour and put it on my server at http://www.amberel.com/test/unicodetest.htm . Just press the button to execute the Ajax function.
The Ajax URL is http://www.amberel.com/test/ajaxunicodetest.htm

This is the complete web page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Ajax UTF-8 test</title>
  <meta name="viewport" id="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

<div id="id-div-main">  
  <p>What it should look like: town=Chaitén</p>  
  <button type="button" onclick="buttonAjaxClick()">Ajax</button>
  <p id="id-p-response"></p>
</div>

</body>

</html>

<script>

function buttonAjaxClick()
{
  try {
    var xmlhttp;
  
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajaxunicodetest.htm", true);
    // Didn't make any difference
    // xmlhttp.overrideMimeType('text/plain;charset=utf-8');
    xmlhttp.send();
  
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
      if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
        if(xmlhttp.status == 200) {
          console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
          document.getElementById("id-p-response").innerHTML = "Ajax response: " + xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
        else if(xmlhttp.status == 404) {
          document.getElementById("id-p-response").innerHTML = "ajaxunicodetest.htm not found";
        }
        else {
          document.getElementById("id-p-response").innerHTML = "ajaxunicodetest status: " + xmlhttp.status;
        }
      }
    };
  }
  catch(err) {
    document.getElementById("id-p-response").innerHTML = "ajaxunicodetest: " + err;
  }
}

</script>
```

I would be most grateful for any ideas as to what to try next as I've been working on this for some time.

Many thanks, Andy

Comment: As far as I see in your code, I receive the data in a not-supported format. 
Meaning your data is not saved in ui8 format in the database/server. Check your saved data in the server/ database

Comment: Thanks Muhamet - but if it was not sent correctly from the server, why does it display correctly if the Ajax URL is entered directly into the browser address bar?

Comment: Try this : 

xmlhttp.overrideMimeType('text/xml; charset=iso-8859-1');

Comment: Thanks, I tried that,and it displayed correctly. But it raises as many questions for me as it answers, because I don't understand why it worked. The more I find out about unicode and character sets, the more complicated it appears to be! iso-8859-1 appears to be an 8 bit character set, not Unicode at all, and it probably only works for European characters. I need to find some non-European characters to try out. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: OK, tried some Greek and, not surprisingly, it didn't work. I think your first comment was right, the problem is at the server end, but because it was a European character it was still showing OK when the Ajax was accessed directly from the address bar. The Unicode is getting lost somewhere in the server internals, so I now need to change tack and investigate that instead, very many thanks for your help on this.

Comment: Apologies for this off-topic comment, but I'm a first time user of the site and I can't see where to upvote or say that a comment was useful - the only thing I can see is to flag it as a serious problem, which is the opposite of what I want to do ;-)

Comment: You can not make a comment as a correct answer, but i can write as an answer and you can mark it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write for overrideMimeType:

```
xmlhttp.overrideMimeType('text/xml; charset=iso-8859-1');
```

> This answer first was written in comments, but after discussing with @Amberel, it worked for him, and we put it here so others can see it too.

Comment: This isn't altogether a fix for my problem, but it was extremely useful because it demonstrated that I was looking in the wrong place for an answer - I need to transfer my attention to the server side instead of the client side. Very many thanks.